# Checking user input in Racket

Tags: racket

I am getting an input from a user for a tex-field% in racket which would look something like this:

```
open button a = fwd; button b = xxx; button s = xxx; close
```

I have verified that it does contain open and close at beginning and end respectively. But now i need to store each of the substrings based on the semicolons to check them for semicolons at the end, among other things. For example, in the example above it should store 3 substrings in a vector/list (whichever is easier). It would be stored as:

```
button a = fwd;
button b = xxx;
button s = xxx;

;input is the name of the string the user enters
(define vec (apply vector (string-split input)))
(define vecaslist(vector->list vec))
(define removedopen (cdr vecaslist))
(define withoutopenandclose (reverse(cdr(reverse removedopen))))
(define stringwithoutopen (string-replace input "open " ""))
(define stringtoderivate (string-replace stringwithoutopen " close" ""))
(define tempvec (apply vector (string-split stringtoderivate ";" #:trim? #f #:repeat? #t)))
```

Attempted to split it by semicolons and place in a vector, but it removes the semicolons. When i do print the length of the vector it correctly shows 3 though, but i would like to keep the semicolons for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string-split`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-split%29%29) with a [regular expression](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html) separator, as follows:

```
(string-split input #rx"(open | close)|(?<=;).")
```

which will output the list:

```
'("button a = fwd;" "button b = xxx;" "button s = xxx;")
```

---

To break down the regular expression:

- `(`exp`)` matches any sub-expression "exp". Hence, `(open )` matches the sub-expression `"open "` in input. Similarly with `( close)`, matching `" close"`.
- `(?<=`exp`)` does a positive look-behind, matching if `"exp"` matches preceding.
- `.` matches anything, such as whitespace, characters etc.
- `|` matches either the expression that comes before it, or after it, trying left first.